# run through an itemArray

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So creating a datatable and running through all the rows in it. Trouble is the DataRow r contains an itemArray[] which I also need to run through.

```
DataTable currentAttribs = //results for datatable;

foreach (DataRow r in currentAttribs.Rows)
          {
            //foreach itemArray[] in r do the following
            {
                  tableRow = "<TR><TD>" + r[0].ToString() + "</TD></TR>";
                  Literal lc = new Literal();
                  lc.Text = tableRow;
                  divFeatureInfo.Controls.Add(lc);
            {
          }
```

Unsure on the syntax for running through the itemArray in 'r'...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a `Object[]`:

```
foreach (DataRow r in currentAttribs.Rows)
{
    foreach (Object obj in r.ItemArray)
    {
          string tableRow = string.Format("<TR><TD>{0}</TD></TR>", r[0]);
          Literal lc = new Literal();
          lc.Text = tableRow;
          divFeatureInfo.Controls.Add(lc);
          // do whatever you need to do with obj
    }
}
```

Comment: was actually thinking I should try that when I was writing out the Q..duh....thanks for the reply though cheers Tim

Comment: - to keep world peace!